# How to get data result from service in angular

Tags: angularjs, http, angular-promise

I have to get the data which comes from API and in this case I used a controller and a service, it's service `daryo.factory('daryoSvc', ['$http', function ($http) {

```
var categories = [];

var categoriesjon = function () {
    $http.get('http://localhost:18737/Category/GetCategories').
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            categories = {
                "one": "two",
                "key": "value"
            };
            alert('g');
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.error(data);
        });

    return categories;
}

var factoryService = {
    categories: categoriesjon
};

return factoryService;
```

}]);`

and here is my Controller function `daryo.controller('daryoCtrl', ['$scope', 'daryoSvc', function ($scope, daryoSvc) {

```
var self = $scope;
self.categories = daryoSvc.categories;

console.log(daryoSvc.categories);
```

}]);`

It's not working correctly,because I didn't use $q promise options and I didn't find a good solving for that, How can I fix that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service returns an empty array. This empty array is then replaced by a new one *once the asynchronous http call succeeds*, but the controller using this service still has a reference to the old, empty array. Another problem is that the controller doesn't even call the service. All it does is store a reference to the service function in the scope.

The code should be

```
var categoriesjon = function () {
    // executed at t1
    return $http.get('http://localhost:18737/Category/GetCategories').
        then(function (response) {
            // executed at t2, long after t1
            var categories = {
                "one": "two",
                "key": "value"
            };
            return categories;
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            console.error(response.data);
        });
};
```

and in the controller:

```
// executed at t0
daryoSvc.categories().then(function(data) {
    // executed at t3
    $scope.categories = data;
});
```

Comment: it returns undifined which data in controller

Comment: Try replacing success() with then() and error() with catch().

Comment: What returns `undefined`? how are you getting that undefined value?

Comment: with console.log(self.categories) which I write in controller

Comment: I'm using this in controller daryoSvc.categories().then(function (data) {
        self.categories = data;
    });

Comment: Where in the controller? Do you understand what asynchronous calls are, and when asynchronous callbacks are executed? I've added when the various parts of the code are executed in my answer.